# How to insert empty space When inserting additional word before existing code In Visual Studio Code(vscode)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to be more productive, 
so I want to find one shortcut.
For example, when I need to insert something front of the codes

**this is a example**
`(--indent--)foo; // before`
then
`(--indent--)var foo // after`

as you can see, this is supposed, that I have a indentation before a code

I have to do these steps

1. move cursor on the front of the word (foo)

   enter a spacebar

   move left

   then insert new word (var)

Is there any command to push a empty space while my cursor is in place? 
Just like `cmd + shift + Enter`(insert code cell Above)?
I'm a user of Vscode(visual studio code)

I want to reduce these steps, Thanks

Comment: use [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros) to combine multiple commands into one and then add a keybinding. for adding literal text use command `type`

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks that would be a good way for many things,